# TFRecord Always Truncated

Tags: tensorflow, tfrecord

When I read from a TFRecord, I always get at some point

```
DataLossError: truncated record at ____
```

I've tried regenerating the TFRecord multiple times, but still the same error.  What's causing it?

Here is how I write the TFRecord

```
with tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(file_name) as writer:
    for _, row in id_table.iterrows():
        id = row['id']
        example = _process_id(id)
        if example is not None:
            writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
```